# Problems with Python indentations when cloning from GitHub

Tags: python, git, github

I have been having problems with cloning for a long time now. I am working with python by the way.

Every time I clone a repository, the indentation just gets all messed up.

Here is an example:

```
class ProductDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        query_params = self.request.query_params
        if 'images_only' in query_params and query_params['images_only'] == 'true':
        return serializers.ImagesOnlyProductDetailSerializer            
        else:
        return serializers.FullProductDetailSerializer
```

As you can see in the function get_serializer the return statement is not where it is suppose to be.On GitHub website it looks fine and indented the way it is suppose to be.

I just realized that when I directly copy a piece of code from Github website and paste it into a text editor, the indentation is wrong as well, even though it looks fine on Github.

Has anyone had this problem before? Am I doing something wrong?

Thank You in advance!

Comment: `Every time I clone a repository` -> how do you clone ?

Comment: Where is this repo ?

Comment: What are the tab settings in your editor?

Comment: Open the file in notepad. You will get to know where the indention is mismatching.

Comment: @stark My settings are indentations using 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same file, with the same content. Only the display differs, because you mixed tabs and spaces.

On GitHub, tabs have the same width as height spaces. I think it might be four spaces in your editor.

You should replace all tabs by height spaces (or, in a terminal: `sed -i "s/\t/        /g" youfile.py`)

Comment: Which one did you try? (The sed command was incorrect, I just fixed it)

Comment: Would you know how to replace tabs by height spaces? Because in sublime text I know I can convert to using indentations with spaces. In my case 4.Thanks!